# VBA Excel Ferramentas referancia?

Tags: vba

No Excel em VBA em Ferramentas, Referencia aparece (AUSENTE: Adobe acrobat 7.0 type library) onde eu posso conseguir esta library e como faço para inclui-la na lista de referencias?

Answer (score 0):

Instale a versão 7 do Adobe Acrobat Reader na sua máquina.